# Change shape of input

Tags: numpy, resnet

I have 4000 vectors. For each vectors we have 1 output value. I want to use ResNet for regression.
Now when input is like this:

> tensor([[0.1902, 0.5367, 0.1589, 0.8982, 0.7908, 0.8838, 0.3854],
> [0.4809, 0.7469, 0.2444, 0.4606, 0.6360, 0.7149, 0.7302],
> [0.9228, 0.1850, 0.0877, 0.9747, 0.5225, 0.4538, 0.8805]])

of the function resnet(inputs), I am getting error:

> RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [3, 7]

How to tackle this?

I tried like inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, 3, 1, 1), but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import torch

t = torch.tensor(
    [
        [0.1902, 0.5367, 0.1589, 0.8982, 0.7908, 0.8838, 0.3854],
        [0.4809, 0.7469, 0.2444, 0.4606, 0.6360, 0.7149, 0.7302],
        [0.9228, 0.1850, 0.0877, 0.9747, 0.5225, 0.4538, 0.8805],
    ]
)

t.unsqueeze(0)
```